# Primefaces time picker to prevent 00:00

Tags: primefaces, datepicker

I'm using the primefaces picker and I was asked to prevent the user from selecting 00:00 from the picker, please I want to know if that is possible

Comment: If I understood your requirement correctly, it can be achieved using minHour, maxHour, minMinute and maxMinute attributes of calendar component.

Comment: again : if I set minMinute="01" I will not be able to write 8:00

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onselect` and `onkeyup` of your calendar to invoke js validation function

for example

```
<p:calendar widgetVar="myValidDateWidget" onselect="myValidatorFunc();" 
   onkeyup="myValidatorFunc();"/>
```

Or if you a submit button just add it to onclick

like this `<h:commandButton onclick="return myValidatorFunc();"...` and in the `myValidatorFunc` func do `return false;` in case of bad input

where in your js add

```
function myValidatorFunc(){
    var enteredDate = myValidDateWidget.getDate();
    var newDate = enteredDate();
    var minutes = enteredDate.getMinutes();
    var hours= enteredDate.getHours();
    //do your checks here...
    //in case of validation error modify the entered date and
    // set the date of your calendar like this myValidDate.setDate(newDate);
}
```

read more about the js Date object: [JavaScript Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: I know about those attributes, this will I will not be able to write 00:01 or 8:00

Comment: I'm using prime faces calendar control with timeOnly="true" .. so the field has no focus in the first place